# Magento addField() does not give you default checkbox

Tags: magento

The module I'm extending adds fields to an admin form using `addField()`. I copied this behavior as I thought I would try to stick to their setup. However, I can not figure out how to add the "use default" checkbox to the right of any of these fields. This is an issue as I have a field to add that needs to be site-specific.

Code for posterity sake:

```
$fieldset->addField('enable_coupon', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('affiliatepluscoupon')->__('Enable Coupon'),
            'name' => 'enable_coupon',
            'note' => Mage::helper('affiliatepluscoupon')->__('If yes then it will create a magento salesrule for this store.'),
            'values' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
        ));
```

To clarify, I am looking for the dynamic checkbox that gets put by admin fields that changes based on what view you are on. This shows up automatically when creating fields through the XML but seems to be left out when adding fields with `addField()`.

Comment: Yes I am on a store view. I am looking into the two answers posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could add a checkbox is

```
$fieldset->addField('enable_coupon', 'select', array(
         ....
  ))->setAfterElementHtml("
                  <span id='span_use_default'>
                     <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='use_default' id='use_default' /> 
                     Use Default
                   </span>
                 ");
```

Also did you check the way they do it in their module?

Comment: I am looking for the automatic "Use Default" checkbox that changes depending on which view your in....if your in default then it doesnt show. This all happens automatically when you use xml to create your admin fields but when you use addField it doesnt show up. Also, the fields they add in this way also do not have this checkbox. Honestly, I can probably just override and add on to the xml but I already overrode this aspect so I was wondering if their was a way to continue using this method.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer simply because its the most basic answer....it wasn't what I was looking for but your right :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but I just wanted to post my solution to this and perhaps spark some other ideas. (and feedback on my way of working)

My initial source: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.be/2013/02/create-system-config-section-with.html

So to add a field (eg: text field):

```
$field = $element->addField( 'myFieldID', 'text',
  array(
    'name'  => 'groups[model_name][fields][var_name][value]', // this value will be saved to the database as module_name/model_name/var_name and you can get it by Mage::getStoreConfig(..)
    'label' => 'Title', // This is the human readable label up front 
    // See how to get the saved value and define inherit in the link above, this is not in scope for this question. Like this you can't ever see the value that you saved.
    'value' => 'My Title', // The initial value
    'inherit' => true, // Checks the inherit cb after the field
    'can_use_default_value' => true, // Can inherit from default level
    'can_use_website_value' => true, // Can inherit from website level
  ))->setRenderer(Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_form_field')); // Use the same renderer as for the system fields (this adds the cb at the end)
```

This is all you need to do to add a checkbox to your fields.
if you wish to add those gray scope texts (eg: [WEBSITE]):

```
$field['scope'] = true; // Display scope label
$field['scope_label'] = '[WEBSITE]';
```

This can be done because the basic Varien Object is defined to implement ArrayAccess

```
class Varien_Object implements ArrayAccess
```

now to render the field just go:

```
echo $field->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Inventory`
and also `catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml`

This looks promising.

```
<legend><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Inventory') ?></legend>
        <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list" id="table_cataloginventory">
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_manage_stock"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manage Stock') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_manage_stock" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][manage_stock]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
                <option value="1"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes') ?></option>
                <option value="0"<?php if ($this->getConfigFieldValue('manage_stock') == 0): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No') ?></option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="inventory_manage_stock_default" value="<?php echo $this->getDefaultConfigValue('manage_stock'); ?>" />

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_manage_stock') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_manage_stock" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_manage_stock]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
            <label for="inventory_use_config_manage_stock" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_manage_stock'), $('inventory_use_config_manage_stock').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: This looks to get default information but not exactly what I am looking for. Im specifically looking for the checkbox that is dynamic based on whether your on default / site or a site view. This comes automatically when adding fields through the xml...

Comment: The system.xml fields are loaded through a different method as far as I know. They probably use something similar to the above .phtml

Comment: Actually the more I look into it the more I realize its a pretty indepth system that would be kind of ridiculous to replicate all just to stick with some bad programming practices. It all kind of starts with Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is quite an ugly solution, but maybe it will work for you. First of all, on product pages there is a custom renderer for each element, that is why it is shown there. So, if you have the following element:

```
$name = $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'label' => Mage::helper('some_helper')->__('Name'),
));
```

you will have to render it with a custom renderer:

```
if ($name)
{
    $name->setRenderer(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element')
    );
}
```

At this point you should have the third column with the `scope-label` class. But the checkbox near it still won't show up. For that we have to set the following for the form:

```
$storeObj = new Varien_Object();
$storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("store");
$storeObj->setId($storeId);
$storeObj->setStoreId($storeId);
$form->setDataObject($storeObj);
```

Now you should see also the checkbox.

This solution is from:

http://code007.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/how-to-show-the-default-checkbox-near-a-magento-attribute/

Answer (score -2):

<sub>OP's solution moved from question to an answer:</sub>

> The more I look into it the more I realize that the system used with
> the XML is a pretty in-depth system that would be kind of ridiculous
> to replicate all just to stick with some bad programming practices. I
> am going to simply add to the XML.
>
> For those wondering how to do it using `addField()`, I *did* figure it
> out. Here is my final code:
>
> ```
> $inStore = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store');
>         $defaultLabel = Mage::helper('affiliateplusprogram')->__('Use Default');
>         $defaultTitle = Mage::helper('affiliateplusprogram')->__('-- Please Select --');
>         $scopeLabel = Mage::helper('affiliateplusprogram')->__('STORE VIEW');
>         $fieldset->addField('enable_coupon', 'select', array(
>             'label' => Mage::helper('affiliatepluscoupon')->__('Enable Coupon'),
>             'name' => 'enable_coupon',
>             'note' => Mage::helper('affiliatepluscoupon')->__('If yes then it will create a magento salesrule for this store.'),
>             'values' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
>             'disabled' => ($inStore && !$data['name_in_store']),
>             'after_element_html' => $inStore ? '</td><td class="use-default">
>           <input id="name_default" name="name_default" type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox config-inherit" ' . ($data['name_in_store'] ? '' : 'checked="checked"') . ' onclick="toggleValueElements(this, Element.previous(this.parentNode))" />
>           <label for="name_default" class="inherit" title="' . $defaultTitle . '">' . $defaultLabel . '</label>
>           </td><td class="scope-label">
>           [' . $scopeLabel . ']
>           ' : '</td><td class="scope-label">
>           [' . $scopeLabel . ']',
>         ));
> ```